# How can I see all styles for one input type checkbox?

Tags: html, sass

I have 10 files that have 10000 lines for each file. I need to choose one style for a checkbox.
But I can't read all those files because it takes a long time to read it.

I have been trying a search to convert CSS to HTML classes.

Note: I don't remember where was used this theme.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to see all the styles for a checkbox without knowing what selectors are used to target them. However, It sounds like you need to override existing styles. Start with the element + an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  //styles
}
```

If that doesn't work, use a `!important`.

```
input[type="checkbox"] { styleProp: !important; }
```

Keep in mind that `!important` is for last resort only, avoid it if you can.